# Calling all wordpress gurus

Tags: wordpress

My friend has a website built on wordpress and the developer has left the country and they can't reach him.

They add some text to the home page recently and since then the right sidebar has dropped. I have trawled through the site looking for unclosed tags etc and can't find the reason, here is the url to the site: [ww.lumleyspetsupplies](http://www.lumleypetsupplies.com/)

Any help appreciated, thought I would post on here to see if anyone had experiance this problem before adn could point me in the right direction

Comment: You may have better luck with this at the dedicated [wordpress.stackechange](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your wordpress install you have page/post revisions,

when you edit your page text and click save, 
it takes a copy and keeps it as a revision,

this is located under the page content,

if its not enabled, go up the very top right hand side and click "screen options" then check the box, "Revisions", now the meta box will appear under the content area, just click an older copy of the homepage text to revert back to the original state, before the mess was made! then copy this text into your content area and save it.

[image]

then compare with the new changes, why it broke, chances are the developer added HTML code into the content area, in which was removed when the page was re-saved!

Marty

**UPDATE**

Look in your CSS file line 217
were it starts:

```
 .latest_bg a:hover{
        background: url(images/newspaper_bg.jpg) 0 -39px;
    /*Start lftside_btm*/
    #lftside_btm{
```

there is a missing } tag on the .latest_bg a:hover

```
.latest_bg a:hover{
    background: url(images/newspaper_bg.jpg) 0 -39px;
}
/*Start lftside_btm*/
#lftside_btm{
```

Comment: I have gone through the revisions and its still broken unfortunately, Is there any reason that the sidebar and content should loose its css

Comment: It has affected all pages which is odd considering the guy said he only added normal text to the home page editor

Comment: it is strange, if you look at the source code of the page, copy and paste all that into dreamweaver, the page renders fine? I couldnt see any missed placed div tags, etc..?

Comment: I can tell you though the styles are lost past this section: lftside_btm

Comment: updated my answer, there was missing closing tag in the CSS file!

Comment: When I looked at the site they were still running an old version of wordpress do you think they were hacked.

Comment: Thank you ever so much I missed that when scanning the css, You have been a real professional at debugging